# Java- Como remover un ArrayList de una lista y añadirlo en otra con exito?

Tags: java, arraylist

Llevo varios días atascada con este código ya casi lo termino pero he llegado a un punto donde no se muy bien como continuar. Mi código es un menú de un garaje de coches donde hay una lista de coches para registrarlos en el garaje y otra para registrar las reparaciones.

**Funcionamiento del menú** --> Se insertan coches en el listado una vez ingresados los coches podemos ver el listado de coches que tenemos en el taller, si no hemos insertado ningún coche avisa que no tenemos coches ingresados, a continuación podemos marcar como reparados usando la matrícula, nos pregunta que coche deseamos reparar y le indicamos la matrícula ( aquí es donde estoy atascada, ya que quiero quitar un coche de la lista de coches y pasarla a reparados, pero me añade en reparados y no me la borra con el remove de la lista anterior), también tenemos otra lista que muestra los coches reparados o si no hay muestra un mensaje, finalmente una opción para retirar los coches de nuestra lista de reparados, como que ya han salido del garaje y la ultima para salir del menú y finalizar el programa.

En el caso de retirar los coches con el remove de mi garaje me pasa exactamente igual que en el caaso de querer eliminar coches de mi registro inicial, no encuentro que debo de estar haciendo mal.

Comparto las 2 clases que tengo.

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    //creamos el ArrayList de Coche en el main para que lo cojan todos los metodos
    static ArrayList <Coche> listadoCoches = new ArrayList<Coche>();
    static ArrayList <Coche> listadoReparados = new ArrayList<Coche>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int preguntaMenu;
        System.out.println("***Bienvenido al programa de registro de coches***");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Tiene "+listadoCoches.size()+" coches en su taller");
            System.out.println("Que operacion desea realizar? Introduzca una opcion:\n1.Registrar un coche\n2.Listado coches"
            + "\n3.Marcar como reparado\n4.Listado coches reparados\n5.Retirar Vehiculo\n6.Salir");
            preguntaMenu = lector.nextInt();

            if(preguntaMenu == 1){
                registrarCoche();
            }
            else if (preguntaMenu == 2){
                listadoCoches();
            }
            else if (preguntaMenu == 3){
                menuReparados();
            }
            else if (preguntaMenu == 4){
                listadoReparados();
            }
            else if (preguntaMenu == 5){
                retirarVehiculo();
            }
        } while (preguntaMenu != 6);
        System.out.println("Fin");
    }

    public static void registrarCoche() {
        String model;
        String color;
        String marca;
        int nPuertas;
        String matricula;
        String cilindrada;
        int fechaMatricula;
        String respuesta;

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        //empezamos un bucle mientras el usuario desee insertar mas usuarios
        do {    
            System.out.println("Quiere registrar un coche?(S/N)");
            respuesta = lector.next();
            //si la respuesta es s volvera a preguntar nombre y suelo sino dira gracias
            if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

                System.out.println("Indique la matricula:");
                matricula = lector.next();

                System.out.println("Indique el anyo de matriculacion:(solo el anyo)");
                fechaMatricula = lector.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Cual es el modelo del coche?");
                model = lector.next();

                System.out.println("Indique su color:");
                color = lector.next();

                System.out.println("Indique la Marca del vehiculo");
                marca = lector.next();

                System.out.println("Introduzca la cilindrada del vehiculo: ");
                cilindrada = lector.next();

                System.out.println("Cuantas puertas tiene el vehiculo?");
                nPuertas = lector.nextInt();

                listadoCoches.add(new Coche(model,color,marca,nPuertas,matricula,cilindrada,fechaMatricula));

            }

        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")); //mientras la respuesta sea s
    }

    public static void listadoCoches() {
        //imprimimos el listado de coches el hashset es recorrido por un for
        System.out.println("\n**Coches pendientes de reparacion**");
        for(Coche c: listadoCoches) {   
            System.out.println("\n"+c.mostrarInfo());
        }   
        System.out.println("\n************************\n");
    }

    public static void menuReparados() {
        String matricula = null;

        System.out.println("Tiene "+listadoCoches.size()+" coches pendientes de reparacion");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            if(listadoCoches.size() > 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del coche que desea reparar\nIntroduzca Salir para finalizar");
                matricula = lector.nextLine();

                if(matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Gracias!");
                }else {
                    listadoReparados.add(new Coche(matricula));
                    //int pos = listadoCoches.indexOf(matricula);
                    listadoCoches.remove(matricula);
                }                               
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("****************************\nNo hay ningun coche para reparar\n****************************");
            }
        }while(!matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"));
    }

    public static void listadoReparados() {
        if(listadoReparados.size() > 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Estos son los coches que ya tiene reparados");
            for(Coche reparado: listadoReparados) { 
                System.out.println("\n"+reparado.mostrarInfoMat());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("****************************\nNo hay ningun coche reparado\n****************************");
        }
    }

    public static void retirarVehiculo() {
        String matricula = null;

        System.out.println("Tiene "+listadoReparados.size()+" coches reparados");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            if(listadoReparados.size() > 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del coche que desea retirar del taller\nIntroduzca Salir para finalizar");
                matricula = lector.nextLine();

                if(matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Gracias!");
                }else {
                    listadoReparados.remove(new Coche(matricula));      
                }
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("****************************\nNo hay ningun coche para retirar\n****************************");
            }
        }while(!matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"));

    }
}
```

**Objeto Coche**

```
public class Coche {
//variables
private String model;
private String color;
private String marca;
private int nPuertas;
private String matricula;
private String  cilindrada;
private int fechaMatricula;


//constructor prefabricado
public Coche(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}


//constructor
public Coche(String model, String color, String marca, int nPuertas, String matricula, String cilindrada,
        int fechaMatricula) {
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.nPuertas = nPuertas;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    this.fechaMatricula = fechaMatricula;
}

//getters y setters

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}



public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}



public String getColor() {
    return color;
}



public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}



public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}



public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}



public int getnPuertas() {
    return nPuertas;
}



public void setnPuertas(int nPuertas) {
    this.nPuertas = nPuertas;
}



public String getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}



public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}



public String getCilindrada() {
    return cilindrada;
}



public void setCilindrada(String cilindrada) {
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
}



public int getFechaMatricula() {
    return fechaMatricula;
}



public void setFechaMatricula(int fechaMatricula) {
    this.fechaMatricula = fechaMatricula;
}


//metodo mostrar info
public String mostrarInfo() {
    return "Matricula: "+matricula+"\nFecha de matriculacion: "+fechaMatricula+"\nModelo: "+model+"\nColor: "+color+"\nMarca: "+marca+
            "\nCilindrada: "+cilindrada+"\nNumero de Puertas: "+nPuertas;
}

//metodo mostrar info
    public String mostrarInfoMat() {
        return "Matricula: "+matricula;
    }
}
```

En el caso de coche escribí dos constructores ya que en reparados no me pide que incluya nada mas solo que la matrícula.

¿Alguna idea? Creo que el fallo se debe a los dos constructores del objeto coche que no tienen que ver entre sí pero no logro descifrarlo, ni como arreglarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En método remove acepta como parámetros el índice del elemento que quieres eliminar o el objeto que espera sea de la misma clase del elemento que quieres eliminar. Tú estas haciendo remove(matricula) y matrícula es string por lo tanto es falso. Según la versión Java:

Java 1.8:

```
    listadoCoches.removeIf(c -> c.matricula.equals(matricula));
```

Java  1.7 :
        Tienes dos opciones:

1. Añadir a la clase `Coche` una función `override` "equals" que  compare los objetos de la clase solo por matrícula y hagas `remove(new Coche(matricula))`. Por esto no funciona el `remove` de `listadoReparados`
2. Iteres por `listadoCoches` hasta encontrar el objeto con la `matricula`. Al encontrarlo borras este objeto.

   ```
       Iterator<Coche> itr = listadoCoches.iterator();


        while (itr.hasNext()) {
             Coche c = itr.next();

             if (c.matricula.equals(matricula)) {
                    listadoCoches.remove(c);
                    break;
            }
       }
   ```

Comment: Hola muchisimas gracias por tu rapidaa respuesta! :) mm he estado probando y no termino de entender, en la versión 1.8 he colocado la linea y tengo un conflicto con el while de mas abajo, si le quito el valor null a string matricula = null; sale correctamente esta primera parte del cogido pero cuando llega al while me dice que matricula necesita un valor, vuelvo a poner valor y sale error de nuevo.

Comment: }while(!matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"));  esta es la linea del while a la que me refiero dentro del menuReparados();

Comment: Si matrícula es null entonces no tiene tipo ni clase por lo tanto cualquier intento se usa matrícula.metodo dará error. En el while agrega (matricula != null && matricula.equalsIgnoreCase("salir"). Ojo en ese while si listadoReparados no tiene elementos te metes a un loop interminable.

Comment: En mi respuesta olvidé el ; final del removeif. Debes verificar en cada punto que utilices matrícula que ewte.no sea null

Comment: jaja justo eso ha pasado se ha metido en un loop jajaja, ya lo he arreglado he eliminado el do while de reparados y de retirar ya que si necesito repetir el proceso en el menú pulso marcar como reparado o retirar de nuevo y ya esta de esta forma he terminado con el problema del valor null :) ya tengo mi programa listo muchas gracias!!! solo me ha quedado hacer algunos pequeños retoques encima del menú principal con el size de los coches del taller Infinitas gracias!!